# EF 6 query get a single entry from other table

Tags: entity-framework-6

I am new to EF 6, then I stumble upon this query and I need to modify it to include the data from OrderDelay table.  I only intend to get a single row from the database so I tried
.Include(m => m.OrderDelay.FirstOrDefault()) instead of .Include(m => m.OrderDelay). But it does not work. Any idea on how to get just a single row for this table?

```
      var res = await _db                
                .Include(m => m.BusAdd)
                .ThenInclude(b => b.Suburb)
                    .ThenInclude(s => s.State)
                     ........
            .Include(m => m.OrderDelay)
            .AsNoTracking()
            .SingleOrDefaultAsync(p => p.Id == id);


        return res;
```

Answer (score 0):

it does return a single row from sql the main `_db.SingleOrDefaultAsync(p => p.Id == id);`

if you use `Include()` sql-c# translation of `outer join` it will satisfy the main condition of the `Where()` and return everything that the included table is linked to.

so it will return

```
   1 main row that satisfy the main condition of SingleOrDefaultAsync(p => p.Id == id);
       multiple foreign table row
```

If you are pertaining to only one result `_db` then do not use/add multiple `Include(x => x.TableName)`

Just use `_db.SingleOrDefaultAsync(p => p.Id == id);`

But if you want to have all the `Joined tables` but only one of each `BusAdd`, `Suburb`, `State`, `OrderDelay`

then insert `.Select()` before/after `SingleOrDefaultAsync()` with conditions of

```
{
    prop1 = row.prop1,
    prop2 = row.prop2,
    BusAdds = row.BusAdds.FirstOrDefault/SingleOrDefaultAsync(add condition here or none),
    Suburbs = row.Suburbs.FirstOrDefault/SingleOrDefaultAsync(add condition here or none),
    States = row.States.FirstOrDefault/SingleOrDefaultAsync(add condition here),
    OrderDelay = row.OrderDelay.FirstOrDefault/SingleOrDefault(add condition here or none)
}
```